# Entity Framework Wizard is Slow

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I've been updating my application to use Entity Framework 6. The code is easy to write if maybe a little confusing to me since I'm converting SQL (which I know) to Linq (which I've never used before) and table joins still have me slowing down to make sure I'm doing it right.

That's going smoothly, if a little awkwardly since I've never used Linq before.

Setup:

```
SQL Server 2016
Visual Studio 2015 update 3
EF Framework 6
```

My problem is that the EF Wizard that updates the table information is slow. It takes about five minutes to refresh the layout. Since I'm making tons of minor changes all day long, this is crippling me. I dropped the compatibility to 110 and it was near instant. Anything higher and it takes a long time. I'm using some functions that were added in 120 and 130 so I want to keep my compatibility level at 130. Dropping it each time to make the map is getting a little annoying, but saves time.

Is there a way to get the near instant refresh without dropping to 110 compatibility mode?

Comment: Hi, I dont´know the internal behaviour of this issue, but I recommend you to use Entity Framework code First and this plugin. You will refresh all the changes very fast. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: This plugin is only for C# so it won't work for me.